# Scraping comment section with Python using Scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I came across a problem while scraping the comments from this [link](https://www.startnext.com/faltenrock-dokumentarfilm/pinnwand/).

Using scrapy shell, I'm wondering why I cannot see the comments in this below `div` section.

```
['<div id="eqWall" data-project-id="53481" data-is-platform-manager="" data-replies-allowed="1"></div>']
```

I got the above output by executing `response.xpath("//section[@class='main-section pin-board-section']/div/div[@id='eqWall']").extract()` using scrapy shell "[link](https://www.startnext.com/faltenrock-dokumentarfilm/pinnwand/)"
Could anyone help me out why I cannot see and what is the solution to scrape the comments.

Thanks

Comment: As Andersson suggests you're trying to load javascript content. Try opening the page source (not inspect, but page source) and you'll see that this div is actually empty.

Comment: @Andersson after so many error I finally got the result as suggested thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Casper Yes using view source I can see empty. Tried spash thing, worked well. Thanks :)